# SVNKit like wrapper for C or C++

Tags: c++, c, wrapper, svn, svnkit

Before I start building one myself;

Is there a wrapper for C or C++ which does the same thing as [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an API provided in C - see the [Subversion  Documentation](http://svn.collab.net/svn-doxygen/)